# How to retrieve the total number of customers (without a "limit") with the stripe API

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I'm working with the PHP stripe API to retrieve a list of all customers for a particular stripe account. I just need the email address of the customer object.

The following function works well however it is only returning 10 customers.

```
  function getListOfCustomers($stripe){
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
        $list_of_customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(array());
        return $list_of_customers['data']; 

    }
```

After reading [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#list_customers) about the API it tells me that the "limit" parameter  (i.e `\Stripe\Customer::all(array("limit" => 3));` )  is optional and the "default limit is 10".
So I guess this is why it is returning only 10 customers.

I would like to return an unlimited amount of customers.
I was wondering does anybody know exactly how to do this?

I read also the following on the [same page](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#list_customers):

> *You can optionally request that the response include the total count of all customers that match your filters. To do so, specify
>   include[]=total_count in your request.*

However it doesnt tell me exactly how to "include this in my request".
I tried the following however I am receiving syntax errors.

```
$list_of_customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(array(), include[]=total_count);
```

and I also tried:

```
$list_of_customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(array(include[]=total_count));
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stripe does not support getting the total count of objects anymore as the feature has been deprecated for a while.

Instead, they recommend looping over all the customers to count them or find a specific one you want. This is really easy with [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) Your code would look like this:

```
$customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(array("limit" => 100));
foreach ($customers->autoPagingIterator() as $customer){
     echo "Current customer: $customer";
}
```

It won't store all the customers at once in $customers, only a page. But when you reach the last one in that page the iterator will automatically fetch the next page for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a go and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: I used your suggestion of auto-pagination. that worked great thanks :)

Comment: Hi I was wondering can you help. Because the call to stripe takes more than around 5 seconds I am getting a gateway timeout error. Can you advise me what to do? thanks

Comment: @Sarah Stripe's API timeout is at 30 seconds, not 5 seconds. You need to change your configuration to allow the requests to run longer.

Comment: @koopah sorry I hadn't got an accurate account of the timeout value when I texted you. thanks for your help. the timeout is happening after approx 32 seconds (not 5).. and its only happening when multiple users are trying to register at the same time. During the testing phase everything worked fine with just one user (myself) registering on this particular server. Ive checked phpinfo and I see the "max_execution_time" is 120.. so is this the value i need to change? thanks

Comment: hey. I added ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); to my php script however it still times out at 32 seconds. you say "You need to change your configuration" so is this the right way to do it? thanks

Comment: @Sarah then you might have to remove `total_count` because it has to count all your customers and can end up timing out.

Comment: so could I do something like retrieve a list of 100 customers a time with multiple ajax requests returning the last index each time. I think multiple ajax requests is the only way as there doesn't seem to be another solution to stop the time out.. thanks for the help... or do you think I could do something like this: whenever there is a new subscriber, I make a request (in the background like a service) to retrieve the list of customers and then store them in a database so whenever I want to retrieve the list of customers I search through my own database instead of the stripe API?

Comment: If you want a better understanding of my application you can check out my question here. thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899053/ajax-error-function-is-executing-with-error-message-gateway-time-out-when-mult?noredirect=1#comment72903138_42899053

Comment: ps actually I wasnt using total_count, I was using autoPagingIterator and it was timing out..

Comment: @sarah hard to say without more details. I'd recommend writing to Stripe support: https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: @Sarah better use queue on your requests, each queue gets 100 saves to your local db and if it `has_more`  customers, dispatch the same queue specifying `starting_after=$last_customer_id`, until there's no more customer left to pull.

Comment: @DexterBengil Thanks. The autoPagingIterator() worked fine in the end. I decided to make the Stripe API request with a webcron job (that ran periodically to update my database) instead of making the request during user registration.

Comment: `total_count` should not be used. "we consider this parameter deprecated and have for a long time and we stopped supporting it" https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/813#issuecomment-523226546

Comment: I was going write a custom pagination method until I saw this ```autoPagingIterator```. Thank you @koopajah

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly for the Customer object, but I was working with the Event object and got it to retrieve all the Event (more than the 100 limit) by writing a recursive function in javascript. Notice how I am using the 'hasMore' field to pull in the next set of 100 Events until 'hasMore' == false.

```html
    const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE)

module.exports = async function importCanceledSubscription ({$models}) {
  const {StripeEvent} = $models

  async function createEvents (last_id) {
    const {events, hasMore, nextId} = await getStripeEvents(last_id)

    let error = false

    for (const e of events) {
      const stripeObj = new StripeEvent
      stripeObj.id = e.id
      stripeObj.object = e.object
      stripeObj.api_version = e.api_version
      stripeObj.created = e.created
      stripeObj.type = e.type
      stripeObj.livemode = e.livemode
      stripeObj.pending_webhooks = e.pending_webhooks
      stripeObj.request = e.request
      stripeObj.data = e.data

      try {
        await stripeObj.save()
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('duplicate found')
        error = true
        break
      }
    }

    if (hasMore && !error) {
      await createEvents(nextId)
    }
  }

  await createEvents()
}


function getStripeEvents (last_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    stripe.events.list({limit: 100, type: 'customer.subscription.deleted', starting_after: last_id}, (err, event) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)

      const events = event.data

      const nextId = event.data[event.data.length - 1].id

      resolve({nextId, events, hasMore: event.has_more})
    })
  })

}
```